# Android: Name of Previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Is there any way to determine what the name of the previous activity in the stack was without passing some data through an Intent Bundle?

Comment: For what purpose? The Activity stack was not designed to be accessed directly by an application.

Comment: I need my activity to behave slightly differently based on where it is being called from.  I can always just use an Intent. I was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: Using a bundle seams to be the most easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this method `ComponentName getCallingActivity()`. Try using it. But it works only if you start an activity using `startActivityForResult()`.

Reference: [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29)